# Send email notification based on timeframe and a given email address from a cell?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

How specifically does the code found in [this article](http://www.withoutthesarcasm.com/automating-google-spreadsheets-email-reminders/) need to be modified to allow for a specified email address column to inform who the reminder should go to?

I have [an example spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0ApRO9YjU_IjrdGx4cVNfRDFlRmRJTVFLRklSQ3U1Y3c&usp=drive_web#gid=0) here with the script provided from the blog post installed.

If it helps explain, my comment to the article author is as follows:

> ...it almost seems as though in your section “Sending the Reminder Email” that the code could reference, instead of a static email address, a cell value that meets the criteria – i.e. the adjacent date column cell is within the proper time range to trigger

And the author's response:

> Yes, that’s certainly something that can be done. It’s honestly a pretty simple extension of the logic – the MailApp.sendEmail call needs to be in the loop, rather than after it.

It looks as though I have the "what" – I just need the "how". I'll take advice or a code example/modification of my installed script

Comment: Your question clearly involves Google Apps Script, then also tag it as such. If you're not really familiar with scripting, I would suggest baby steps (or see `what about Bob`). Ask simple questions, and get simple answers and learn on the go. Best is to include a Google Spreadsheet and show the expected result.

Comment: Hi, thank You for your suggestions; I have edited my question. What is "what about Bob"?

Comment: Haha Drew, that's a movie, starring Bill Murray and Richard Dreyfuss. Check IMDb for more info.

Comment: Ah, baby steps ... got it. :)

Comment: Drew, somehow the article link seems broken....Yesterday it was working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the final result/answer:

```
function checkReminder() {
  // get the spreadsheet object
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  // set the first sheet as active
  SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheets()[0]);
  // fetch this sheet
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();

  // figure out what the last row is
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();

  // the rows are indexed starting at 1, and the first row
  // is the headers, so start with row 2
  var startRow = 2;

  // grab column 5 (the 'days left' column)
  var range = sheet.getRange(startRow,4,lastRow-startRow+1,1 );
  var numRows = range.getNumRows();
  var day_values = range.getValues();

  // Now, grab the reminder name column
  range = sheet.getRange(startRow, 2, lastRow-startRow+1, 1);
  var reminder_info_values = range.getValues();

  // Grab Status
  range = sheet.getRange(startRow, 5, lastRow-startRow+1, 1);
  var status_values = range.getValues();

  // Grab email addresses
  range = sheet.getRange(startRow, 6, lastRow-startRow+1, 1);
  var email_values = range.getValues();

  var msg = "";

  // Loop over the days left values
  for (var i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
    var d1 = new Date();
    var d2 = day_values[i][0];
    var days_left = Math.floor((d2 - d1) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    var status = status_values[i][0];

    if(days_left == 2 && status.toLowerCase() != "completed") {
      var reminder_name = reminder_info_values[i][0];

      msg = "Heads up, the target completion date for " + reminder_name + " is in " + days_left + " days.\n";
      MailApp.sendEmail(email_values[i][0], "Reminder Spreadsheet Message", msg);
      //Logger.log(msg);
    }
  }
};
```

I should note that it is still necessary to set a time based trigger to run the script daily, as mentioned in the original blog post

Answer (score 1):

Here's a pseudocode version of what he was saying:

What he wrote...

```
counter = 0

loop rows {
    if something {
        add to message
        increment counter
    }
}

if counter {
    send message to one person
}
```

What you need to write:

```
counter = 0

loop rows {
    if something {
        make message
        send message to person in row
    }
}
```

You will need to access the data from the email column as well. I'll leave the rest to you to work out, except to say that you should read [this article](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/best_practices) on how to get the data out of your sheet efficiently.